# Error publishing Website VS 2005

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I'm trying to publish a ASP.NET Website using VS 2005 and i am running into some trouble.
The Publish always fails and it does not present any error messages.

The Output is as follows:

```
...
Publishing folder bin/pt/_vti_cnf...
Publishing folder bin/ru...
Publishing folder bin/ru/_vti_cnf...
Publishing folder bin/tr-TR...
Publishing folder bin/tr-TR/_vti_cnf...
Publishing folder bin/zh-CHS...
Publishing folder bin/zh-CHS/_vti_cnf...
Publishing folder bin/zh-CHT...
Publishing folder bin/zh-CHT/_vti_cnf...
Publishing folder bin/_vti_cnf...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The error list is empty (some warnings but as long as they are warnings it should be ok, right?) and i have no idea what might be causing the error. Can anyone shed some light over this?

UPDATE:

I deleted all the vti_cnf folders and it didn't change anything. At least with success.
The message is now:

```
Publishing folder bin/ru...
Publishing folder bin/tr-TR...
Publishing folder bin/zh-CHS...
Publishing folder bin/zh-CHT...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Inside this zh-CHT folder there's only a Ajax Control Toolkit .dll as in zh-CHS folder and tr-TR and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible a file is read only, locked by the OS, or a security rights issue. Try publishing to another folder and see if you still get that same error.

Comment: I changed the location and tried to publish to "C:\Test" but it still failed with the same output message.

Comment: Do you have any build events? Can you post your publish settings?

Comment: Build events? What do you mean?

Comment: You probably don't but you can see the build events if you right click on the Project, Select Properties, and go to the Compile tab. There should be a button near the bottom called Build Events... Click on that and a new window will popup that will show you any special code that runs before or after the project builds.

Answer (score 0):

Check the things below;

1. If your target folder is opened in anywhere ( because windows can't write data in opened folders)
2. If you published it before there will be files in obj folder delete them and republish

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned about the `_vti_cnf` folders.

Those are typically configuration files for front page and have absolutely no reason to be deployed out of visual studio.  At the very least you need to exclude those from your local project or, better yet, flat out delete them (again, from local).

If you are not using FrontPage extensions, which I highly recommend you turn off anyway, then delete them from the server as well and have frontpage extensions disabled.  There are MANY much better ways of deploying a site.

Note, Dreamweaver also uses FP extensions for deployment.  However, those files are also not stored locally as they have no place in your application.

Most likely the problem is simply that you are trying to overwrite server files that you have no reason to actually be publishing.

Comment: I didn't use FrontPage on the development of the site. Are you positive that erasing all the vti_cnf folders will not have a negative impact on the project?

Comment: @Seth:  Yes.  However, as will all changes you should have everything under source control.  In the event it's not you should at the very least have a backup of your code.

Comment: I deleted all those folders and it didn't produce any effect. Please see my now updated first post for more details.